# Switching from AFNetworking to RestKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, restkit, afnetworking

I started developing my application using AFNetworking. Everything went OK till I want to use core data. I know there is an additional class (AFIncrementalStore) for that. But because I'm new to IOS-development and there is not a lot of information about that. I decided to switch to RestKit because here is a lot more information. Now, I followed a tutorial about AFNetworking. Here I created an API class which this method in it.

```
+(API *)sharedInstance
{
    static API *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^ {
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAPIHost]];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

#pragma mark - init
//intialize the API class with the destination host name

-(API *)init
{
    //call super init
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil){
        //initialize the object
        user = nil;

        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

        // Accept HTTP Header; see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)loginCommand:(NSMutableDictionary *)params onCompletion:(JSONResponseBlock)completionBlock{
    NSLog(@"%@%@",kAPIHost,kAPILogin);
    NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest = [self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:kAPILogin parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData){
        //TODO: attach file if needed

    }];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:apiRequest];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
        //success!
        NSLog(@"SUCCESSSS!");
        completionBlock(responseObject);
    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
        //Failure
        NSLog(@"FAILUREE!");
        completionBlock([NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[error localizedDescription] forKey:@"error"]);
    }];
    [operation start];

}
```

This handles the communication between my webservice and application. 
In the viewControler itself I call this method like this.

```
   /*  [[API sharedInstance] loginCommand:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_txtLogin.text,@"email",_txtPass.text,@"pwd", nil] onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json){
     //completion
         if(![json objectForKey:@"error"]){
             NSLog(@"status %@",[json valueForKeyPath:@"data.status"]);
             if([[json valueForKeyPath:@"data.status"]intValue] == 200){
                  // Everything is oké, and login is succesfull
             }else{
                 //show validation
             }
         }else {
             NSLog(@"Cannot connect to the server");
         }
     }];*/
```

This is how I do this in AFnetworking. But what are the differences when I do this in RestKit. I searched for tutorials. But after the update from RestKit 1.0 to 2.0 a lot of these tutorials are outdated. So I hope anybody can help me out with this!

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

I used this tutorial for using RestKit. It shows you how to use it and you can learn the other details. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFi9t8NW0oY

Comment: Please avoid posting link-only answers; they disappear unexpectedly, their contents cannot be searched, and it is difficult to see whether they actually answer the question.